# Missing nuget version: Microsoft.Identity.Client.1.1.1-alpha0414

Tags: azure-ad-msal

We have been piloting a new app that uses MSAL.NET for auth and the nuget package version we were using is 1.1.1-alpha0414. 
Unfortunately our VSTS CI Android builds are failing as that version can no longer be found, and indeed I cannot see that version listed on nuget at all.

We can of course update to the latest (at time of writing 1.1.4-preview0002) but that will break our dev cycle, upgrades to nugets and dependencies need to be planned etc.

Has that version been deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my question is actually wrong. The specific version of this nuget package was actually on the overnight feed, not on nuget.org, and I believe it has now been deleted as a housekeeping task.